# How to load large amount of data for training machine learning models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, bigdata, data-science

The file is about 2GB with around 1 million records and has more than 200 columns. I have tried creating a dataframe using `pd.read_csv()` during the whole night but the kernel froze and was not able to finish creating the dataframe.

What should I do to load the large amount of dataset?

Comment: Do you need all of the columns? If not, restrict them in read_csv. Do you read the same csv often? Save it to a faster format like parquet or feather or pickle for faster loads later. Or put it into some database first. Good ole sql or some other big data db. One problem with csv is its unknown length so its read and then converted to a dataframe more than doubling the memory of the dataset.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see how you're loading the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with "Pandas", as it holds the dataset in RAM, it allows a greater speed in the performance of specific calculations (Try creating dataframes for the management of your data). You can also use "Dask" for performing distributed and parallel computations.